Pronunciation of N in "envy"? The name of my personal pronunciation, an approximant?
I don't know phonology. I browsed Wikipedia pages of IPA, the approximant category list and the IPA chart of 2020, but I may be missing things.
Question 1: What's the exact pronunciation of N in the English word "envy"?  All dictionaries I saw say it's normal /n/, but I'm not sure.
Whatever the accepted/common/variant pronunciations are, my personal way is e"nv"-vy, where  "nv" is "a nasal approximant like n" + v. I mean the tongue tip and also the mid part are lifted, similar to /n/, but the tip doesn't touch the palate. The teeth are same as "v". The airflow goes through the nose. I'm not sure if it doesn't go through the mouth, but blocking the mouth does not seem to change the sound much.
I don't think it's ɹ nor ø̃: Compared to ɹ, I also raise the mid of the tongue. Unlike ø̃, the lips form is not essential.
Question 2: What's the name of this consonant?

I have a similar thing with /n/ before /s/ in Italian (my native language) and English: the tongue never comes into contact with the roof of the mouth like it's supposed to with [n], but also, I don't feel that I'm just pronouncing a nasal vowel, as I can do that and it sounds different. When other people with different accents do pronounce actual [n] before /s/, it sounds like [nts] to me.

the n sound in envy starts with this phoneme: /e/ You can't say the letter n in English without it. Then the /n/

A nasal consonant pronounced with the same labiodental place of articulation as the consonant [v] is phonetically transcribed as [ɱ] in the IPA: see the Wikipedia article "Voiced labiodental nasal". Nasals are normally categorized as occlusives rather than approximants, but the distinction is rarely contrastive, and that page suggests it might be questionable which category [ɱ] belongs to, since apparently it may be physiologically difficult for many people to accomplish full occlusion with a labiodental place of articulation. If you really want to emphasize that a voiced nasal labiodental sound is an approximant, you can instead use the transcription [ʋ̃].
In English, the sound [ɱ] is not regarded as its own phoneme, so you'll never see it between phonemic slashes: only /n/ or /m/. Dictionaries don't note that words like envy can be pronounced with [ɱ] because the difference between [ɱ] and [n] in this context is not meaningfully significant to English speakers.
The use of [ɱ] in English as an optional allophone of /n/ before /v/ or /f/ is discussed in "Local assimilation" (Elizabeth Zsiga, 2011).

In a case like envy, it may also just be realised as [ˈɛ̃ʋ̃ːɪ], with nasalisation merging into both the preceding vowel and the following /v/.
